# git diff doesn't print an error for bad filenames

Tags: git, git-diff

Let's say that I issue the following command:

```
git diff hash1 hash2 -- MyFile.java
```

If the versions of the file in the two hashes are identical, then git returns no output. That seems reasonable and expected. However, if instead I pass a bad filename like this:

```
git diff hash1 hash2 -- MyFile.javaaaa
```

instead of getting an error, git again returns no output. I know that this behavior isn't universal; there are other git commands that do complain about a bad filename. But that's not happening here. And it's a real problem, because I can't differentiate between the case where there really is no difference and the case where I've just fat fingered the filename.

This can't be right. What am I missing? Is there some setting I can change?

Answer (score 2):

In [git diff's document](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-ltpathgt82308203), `<path>` "are used to limit the diff to the named paths", which sounds like that it acted like a filename filter, rather than a filename specifier.

That is, if you enter a filename that this file not exists, you will filter out all files, remaining nothing in the output.